# Why do enemies randomly turn hostile?

Tags: gtfo

When I silently kill an enemy with my melee weapon, sometimes an enemy quite far away randomly seems to turn hostile and alerts everyone in the room. In a room with about 8 or 9 enemies, this usually means each player taking heavy damage, and heavy ammo expenditure.

Why does this happen? And how can I avoid this?

Comment: If you are talking about the sleepers, it seems with them it is a bit different than with the other enemies. Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/493520/discussions/4/1644304412665843587/

Comment: @AnneKate This thread indicates that people aren't really aware why this happens, just that I'm not the only one. It seems disappointing

Comment: I know, but it seems that it is something random. Either a bug or a not so convenient feature. The most plausible answer seems to be that they, as in sleepers are somehow connected, and it happens because of that. Yet even that doesn't fully address why some of them keep sleeping while others start attacking.

Comment: @AnneKate I'm willing to put this under the "It's early access" umbrella. If it's a bug, it needs patching. If it's a feature, it needs explanation.

Comment: That thread seems to go with the idea that it's an intended mechanic to make sure every room doesn't have zero risks. I personally find this unlikely, but it's something to consider.

Comment: @Corsaka Removing player agency and just arbitrarily deciding that you will fail now is...questionable at best, if this is truly what was done.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing, and there actually is some mechanics involved.  I've done some research and testing, and found that [this video](https://youtu.be/hZBexJkQFSg?t=47) is a pretty good one to watch to understand their mechanics.  Here is what I've learned:

- When a sleeper is glowing white, it's performing a "scan".  If you are close enough, if you make noise either by moving, crouching, standing up, killing another sleeper, etc., it will progress to its next alert stage (the pulsing heartbeat-like stage).  Here's a picture of one glowing white:

[image: Glowing White Sleeper]

- You can force a sleeper to perform a scan by making noise, or shining your flashlight on it quickly.  Killing a sleeper while another one is nearby will cause it to start scanning.
- If a sleeper starts pulsing, **hold still**.  You can look around, but definitely do not move at all or make any other kinds of noises!  If you do move or make a sound, it will become fully alert (glow red), and the chaos will ensue.

It can be difficult to dispatch groups of sleepers silently since the sleepers tend to scan all at different times, making it challenging to pick them off one by one.  You have to either time your kills between the scans, or you can force the sleepers to change their scan cycles by making sounds or shining your flashlight on them quickly.  By doing this, you can make timing things easier on yourself.

Two more tips - the video pointed out that when your cross hair shrinks in size, it means you are within melee distance of a sleeper.  This is good to know when you are trying to charge up your melee attack to hit them.  Second, swinging your melee weapon does not count as making noise, so even if a sleeper is scanning, you can swing your melee weapon without causing a disturbance.

Comment: Thank you for your write-up, but this occurs specifically when enemies were not glowing. So imagine a sleeper close to me and a sleeper across the room. The sleeper far away just stopped scanning and returned to a dormant state. I kill the sleeper close to me with a melee weapon. Suddenly, the sleeper across the room goes straight to alarm mode.

Comment: @MechMK1 while researching for my answer, I came across a lot of people claiming there are bugs around stealth in various forums and posts, such as [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/493520/discussions/0/2659872073617794782/) that claim the distance for stealth kills seems broken.  It's quite possible there might be a bug especially since the game is in early access, but it's too hard to tell for sure.  The actual mechanics seem to be what I've described in my answer, but as for random sleepers waking up from "miles away," there doesn't seem to be any clear answer for that.